# PowerShell Line Counter "Plugin" Function (Bonus Inside)

Tags: powershell, plugins, command-line

Spent several hours creating this 'plugin' for PowerShell.
Also this is my first post and I wanted to contribute something...

I really don't mind if it's already out there because I wanted to train my skills. But if you know something alike do tell.
The license for this is "Public Domain".
If you see room for improvement do it and please post it here as well :)

It's a function you will import that will display a line-counter together with `Get-Content` for you.

I'll post a pastebin link since there's a limit that I am pretty sure I will exceed.

**Constructive Feedback is highly appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line you get from `Get-Content` has a property `ReadCount` which contains what you are looking for. That's why it's generally a good idea to check out the properties of the objects you are working with.

```
gc test.txt | % { "{0:D3}: {1}" -f $_.ReadCount, $_ }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://pastebin.com/zGL7xVpV

.SYNOPSIS

Get-Lines gives you line numbers and has some of Get-Content's functionality among other things.
I programmed it between 7th of March and 8th of March because I was compiling Java code within the
PowerShell and I wanted to have a "Type MyClass.java -displayLineNumbers"

Comment: Forgive me if im missing something but you could just do something like this to get the same thing `$line = 0; Get-Content C:\temp\data.log | ForEach-Object{"{0:D3}:{1}" -f $line++, $_}`. If need be you could convert that into and `index` and `line` object so as to not ruin the original data: `ForEach-Object{[pscustomobject]@{Index=$line++;Line=$_}}`

Comment: @Matt Thanks! Yes haha that is probably the way to go. I am still learning... :)